# Difference of SeletionKey.cancel() and iterator.remove() - java

Tags: java

What is the difference of key.cancel() and iterator.remove()?
Removing the key from iterator isn't removing  the key from selector too?

Suppose that:

```
...
SelectionKey key = (SelectionKey) iterator.next();
..
Iterator<SelectionKey> iterator  = selectedKeys.iterator();
...
```

Answer (score 2):

Javadoc for SelectionKey says following..

A selection key is created each time a channel is registered with a selector. A key remains valid until it is cancelled by invoking its cancel method, by closing its channel, or by closing its selector. **Cancelling a key does not immediately remove it from its selector**; it is instead added to the selector's cancelled-key set for removal during the next selection operation.

iterator.remove, remove it from the list.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `remove()` on an `Iterator`, it just removes the object the Iterator is currently on from the list. It doesn't call any methods on the object, it doesn't affect it in any way -- it just takes it out of the list.

When you call `cancel()` on a `SelectionKey`, it happens to do the same thing, but that's because `cancel()` requests that the list remove the object. In addition, it's not guaranteed to happen instantly, whereas using `remove()` immediately removes the item from the list. `cancel()` just makes it useless and, when it gets a chance, removes it from the list.